# Xamarin forms, Updating the main UI thread fails when the user switches between pages too quickly

Tags: c#, xamarin

In one of the pages on my application, I have a vertical CollectionView with a slider, I want the app to remember the last position the user was in when they leave, so I use Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread when the page appears to scroll down to that position, and it works as expected, except if the pages are switched quickly(less than 3 seconds), In that case the app completely ignores the scrolling function and just stays in the first index.

I tried checking the values of the indexes and whether OnAppear() functions are excepted, and they are.

Comment: Do you think that the description you've given is enough or should you post code too?

Comment: Since I cannot see any code you implemented.

I think you should use the MVVM pattern with the observable collection, then use the Dependency injection to control the ready data state.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Unclear exactly what happens when, when pages are switched quickly. Most importantly, is the scroll being attempted after the page is no longer visible (because you've switched to another page)? Maybe add Debug.WriteLines both in OnAppear and OnDisappear, of that page, and other pages. And a WriteLine inside that BeginInvoke. Print value of IsVisible as well as the current scroll index. You don't mention going "back in nav stack", so I can't mentally picture how it matters if pages are switched quickly.

Comment: When the page loads, It calls Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread() to update the UI, It only contains one line that calls ScrollTo on a collection view to return to the previous index before leaving the page. Everything works fine but If I switch from the page that contains the collection to any other page and immediately return to it before the other one loads, ScrollTo is ignored and the collection view remains in the first index. I tried adding other code like debugging messages in the invoke main thread function and OnAppear() and its executed, but ScrollTo keeps getting ignored

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post more code snippets or a basic demo so that we can test on our side?